# How to store only the time in the database?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql-9.1

I'm using rails 3, I want to store start_time and end_time. Since rails does not support date ranges.

which data type should I use to store the time without the date to later make comparisons?

This is my database schema with the tsrange data types in the table Schedules (which datatype should I use to replace it?).

```
CREATE TABLE Doctors
(
id INTEGER UNIQUE,
name VARCHAR(size)
);

CREATE TABLE Schedules
(
id INTEGER,
doctor_id INTEGER,
start_time tsrange,
end_time tsrange,
day VARCHAR(size)
);

CREATE TABLE Appointments
(
id INTEGER,
doctor_id INTEGER,
aday DATE
);
```

Comment: So you're just looking to represent a value like "9:30 am"?

Comment: yes, and I want to be able to compare the times.

Comment: If you use `time` format for the column type, MySQL (for example) will store it as just the time, which is great, but Rails will then convert that to a proper Time (with Time Zone) and attach a Date to it and a Time Zone, which is not ideal in most cases.

Answer (score 8):

The :time datatype is probably what you're looking for.

Also, this question really helped me when I was trying to learn about the differences between date/time datatypes in rails:

[In Ruby on Rails, what's the difference between DateTime, Timestamp, Time and Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928275/in-ruby-on-rails-whats-the-difference-between-datetime-timestamp-time-and-da)

You should also consider using datetime datatype , and simply converting it using strftime, e.g

```
 t = Time.now
 t.strftime("%I:%M%p")
```

This will take a date/time and simply format at as Hour/Minute/AM|PM, leaving out the date.

Comment: But the time datatype add a date also, or not?

Comment: It will store hour/minute/second values. I also edited my question above.