# Rails applications and TimeZone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, utc

Does Rail handle TimeZone by itself or we should code for it? 
For example a doctor orders medicine for a patient in NewYork like 6 hours a day... then flies to California and open the chart of that patient whom had visited in NewYork and looks at his medicine schedule ... How does Rails handle this situations?

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that Rails converts all the time types (`:datetime`, `:time`, `:timestamp`) to UTC before storing them in the database.

If you want to ensure local time is always shown, then you need to call `TimeZone#utc_to_local` on your data before displaying it.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-local

There is some more good background information in this question:

[In Ruby on Rails, what's the difference between DateTime, Timestamp, Time and Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928275/in-ruby-on-rails-whats-the-difference-between-datetime-timestamp-time-and-da)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Actually, the method you need may be localtime. Sorry for any confusion.