# Time attribute gets changed when saved to database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model, called event, with a time attribute. I'm setting it to `Time.now`, and it I log the time on the object before save, its a second or two after the current time, as expected. But once the object is saved and then found in the database, the time is different, with a the date part being January 1st, 2000. What's causing this, and what can I do to make sure my times are saved correctly? EDIT: the column type is time, database is SQLite.

Comment: Which database? What is the column type?

Comment: If column type is Datetime and you saved `Time.now` it should work properly

Comment: Please also give the column type, database adapter as suggested by @muistooshort

Comment: If you post the migration for Event we can give you a more specific response.  Your migration probably has `t.time: time` which you may want to change to `t.datetime` per my response below - but we can't be 100% sure until you show us.

Comment: Knowing what the "time" values look like inside the database would also be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you may be saving a `time` object rather than a `date` object.

Active record allows you to use `time`, `date`, and `datetime` objects.

If you are using a `time` or `date` object, however, they are still kind of (*bad way of explaining it*, see the linked response below for more details) full `datetime` objects.  When you read them the date will be present on `time` objects (typically as January 1'st, 2000).

---

> *What can I do to make sure my times are saved correctly?*

If saving / reading the full `datetime` is important for this field, you may want to consider changing the migration representing your model to use:

```
object.datetime
```

. . .  rather than:

```
object.time
```

---

See this response for some more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3929047/1026898

Comment: I don't think "they are still kind of full `datetime` objects" is accurate. If I create a date column with PostgreSQL it will be a date in Ruby and a date inside the database.

Comment: You're right.  That's part of why I said it was a bad way of explaining it.  It's a good amount of information that would have expanded the post unnecessary.  That's why I added the link to a more descriptive answer.

Comment: But you still have three distinct types and I don't see where 2000-01-01 would come from.

Comment: There are a lot of variables to this problem that we can't see here that may be the specific issue causing this (different databases can vary in how they handle time-like values, for example).