# strange behavior on datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following record on my data base:

```
"availability_date" : ISODate("2014-09-29T15:45:00.000Z")
```

and I trying to get the differences between two datetime like this:

```
@minutes = (((@date_time.to_time) - (Time.now))/60).round
```

but the @date_time have the following value and I don't understand why???

> "2014-09-29 17:45:00 +0200"

could someone help me please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using MongoDB?  Can you connect the code between availability_date and @date_time?  I assume there is some missing code here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any problem, The datetime in @date_time is the same as in your database. The +0200 at the end means that it is written in a different timezone, here GMT +2, I guess. It is probably the time zone that your computer uses.

What is the result you expect ? Can you give an example ? And be sure to read the answer to [In Ruby on Rails, what's the difference between DateTime, Timestamp, Time and Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928275/in-ruby-on-rails-whats-the-difference-between-datetime-timestamp-time-and-da)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert them to integer using `to_i` m this give you the number of seconds in unix time, the n it's probably more easy to do a calculation