# ActiveRecord + Pry confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sinatra, padrino, pry

This is confusing me no end.

In a rake task, I am saving new records on the DailyScore model with the following code:

```
def save_record_as_daily_score_object(data)
    @ds = DailyScore.where(date: data[:date]).first_or_create!  
    @ds.update!(data)
    binding.pry
end
```

The pry output is as follows:

```
[10] pry(main)> data
=> {:date=>"2015-09-02",
:mail=>-0.6,
:times=>-7.1,
:telegraph=>-2.2,
:guardian=>-4.0,
:express=>-0.1,
:independent=>-3.2,
:average=>-3.4}  

[11] pry(main)> @ds
=> #<DailyScore:0x000001098121a8
 id: 4975,
 mail: nil,
 telegraph: nil,
 times: nil,
 average: nil,
 guardian: nil,
 independent: nil,
 express: nil,
 date: nil,
 created_at: 2016-05-16 13:10:03 UTC,
 updated_at: 2016-05-16 13:10:03 UTC>

 [12] pry(main)> @ds.average
 => -3.4
 [13] pry(main)> @ds.date
  => "2015-09-02"
 [14] pry(main)> @ds.persisted?
  => true
 [15] pry(main)> DailyScore.last
=> #<DailyScore:0x000001086810d8
 id: 4975,
 mail: nil,
 telegraph: nil,
 times: nil,
 average: nil,
 guardian: nil,
 independent: nil,
 express: nil,
 date: nil,
 created_at: 2016-05-16 13:10:03 UTC,
 updated_at: 2016-05-16 13:10:03 UTC>
 [16] pry(main)> DailyScore.last.average
=> nil
```

What is going on here? Why can't Pry access my variable attributes? And is the record actually being saved or not?

UPDATE:
Checking in the console, the behaviour is the same if I simply create a new object. I'm using the Padrino framework, and a Postgres db.

```
2.0.0 :001 > ds = DailyScore.new(date:"2016-01-01")
 => #<DailyScore id: nil, mail: nil, telegraph: nil, times: nil, average: nil, guardian: nil, independent: nil, express: nil, date: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
2.0.0 :002 > ds.date
 => "2016-01-01"
2.0.0 :003 > ds
 => #<DailyScore id: nil, mail: nil, telegraph: nil, times: nil, average: nil, guardian: nil, independent: nil, express: nil, date: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Is it a problem with the model? Here is the original migration:

006_create_daily_scores.rb

```
class CreateDailyScores < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def self.up
     create_table :daily_scores do |t|
       t.float :average
       t.datetime :date
       t.float :express
       t.float :independent
       t.float :guardian
       t.float :telegraph
       t.float :mail
       t.float :times
       t.timestamps
     end
   end

   def self.down
     drop_table :daily_scores
   end
 end
```

Have now added another column day:date - using :date instead of :datetime - to check if it was a quirk with :datetime, but behaviour is the same.

Comment: What happens if you call `@ds.valid?`

Comment: [18] pry(main)> @ds.valid? => true

Comment: Is @ds.changes == [] both before and after update?

Comment: pry(main)> @ds.changes  => {} - both before and after the update! call

Comment: Hm... Very odd, is this specific to Pry?

Comment: Not sure. How else would you suggest I check?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112061/discussion-between-jonathan-w-and-anthony-e).

Comment: What happens if you don't use `first_or_create!`?

Comment: @PetrGazarov That's a good point. first_or_create isn't threadsafe.

Comment: Can you try @ds.reload!

Comment: Where exactly is the `save_record_as_daily_score_object` method defined? In the rake file? In a model? I don't observe this behavior under rails if the method resides in model or in rake. But judging from the tags, your scenario might be more complex?

Comment: @BoraMa good point, will test moving it to rake itself.

Comment: Have moved save_record_as_daily_score_object to tasks.rake, and changed first_or_create! to find_or_create_by, but still same behaviour. @PetrGazarov could you suggest another replacement for first_or_create! ?

Comment: I will try replacing :datetime with another format to see if the behaviour is fixed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928275/in-ruby-on-rails-whats-the-difference-between-datetime-timestamp-time-and-da

Comment: Did you define `attr_accessor` in your model by any chance? If so, you should remove it because it is overriding the attributes.

Comment: Amazing @PetrGazarov! Please make this into an answer so I can mark as correct. And thanks so much for coming back to this, I was on the point of despair as my whole project was on hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you called `attr_accessor` in your model with your model attributes, which overrode default accessors provided by Rails (the accessors are called by `update` and `new` methods). [Note this doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord%3A%3ABase-label-Overwriting+default+accessors), for reference, if you *do* want to override accessors one day.

Removing `attr_accessor` from your model will do the trick!