# How to check if variable is Date or Time or DateTime in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time

Any easy way to check if a variable / object is of `Date` / `Time` / `DateTime` type? Without naming all the types

Comment: Why do you want to check it? Some of them share methods that allows you to use them without knowing what type it is?

Comment: I have a Rails active record that has 2 attributes that are Time, I need to do a `.map` to convert each attribute that is Time to datetime. Would be great that in the future the type of time could be changed in the DB, hence the question.. but I guess I'm just kinda curious now...

Comment: Curious why the downvote? .. Is there a way to ask the people who downvoted? I must have made somebody furious in this `forum`

Comment: No you can't ask why someone down voted it... Don't let it get to you, I'm confused a lot of the time people down vote things as well.  You asked a simple question and got straight to the point... someone who doesn't like that style ( i.e. they want a draw out reason of why you just asked your question. not necessary IMO) could have down voted it.  But as others have noted the `. instance_of?` or `.class` is probably the best solution to finding the class of an object in Ruby.  GL with your work!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Another option:

```
def is_datetime(d)
  d.methods.include? :strftime
end
```

Or alternatively:

```
if d.respond_to?(:strftime)
  # d is a Date or DateTime object
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It led me to this solution : `d.respond_to?(:strftime)`

Answer (score 6):

you can inspect the class of a object doing

```
object.class
```

It should return Date, String or whatever it is. You can also do the reverse and check if an object is an instance of a class:

```
object.instance_of?(class)
```

where class is the one you want to check (String, Date), returning true/false

Answer (score 5):

If you want to verify the object, here you have a couple of examples:

```
nisevi@nisevi ~:$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require "date"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require "time"
=> true
irb(main):003:0> d = Date.new
=> #<Date: -4712-01-01 ((0j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb(main):004:0> dt = DateTime.new
=> #<DateTime: -4712-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((0j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>  
irb(main):005:0> t = Time.new
=> 2016-06-22 21:33:09 +0200

irb(main):014:0> d.instance_of?(Date)
=> true
irb(main):015:0> d.instance_of?(DateTime)
=> false
irb(main):016:0> d.instance_of?(Time)
=> false
irb(main):017:0> dt.instance_of?(DateTime)
=> true
irb(main):018:0> dt.instance_of?(Time)
=> false
irb(main):019:0> dt.instance_of?(Date)
=> false
irb(main):020:0> t.instance_of?(Time)
=> true
irb(main):021:0> t.instance_of?(DateTime)
=> false
irb(main):022:0> t.instance_of?(Date)
=> false
```

Also I think that TimeZone is from [Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) and not from Ruby.

As per your comment if you want to convert a Time object to DateTime I think that something like this it should work:

```
def time_to_datetime time
  return time.to_datetime if time.instance_of?(Time)
  false
end
```

Here you have some code:

```
irb(main):026:0> t.instance_of?(Time)
=> true
irb(main):027:0> t.methods.sort.to_s
=> "[:!, :!=, :!~, :+, :-, :<, :<=, :<=>, :==, :===, :=~, :>, :>=, :__id__, :__send__, :asctime, :between?, :class, :clone, :ctime, :day, :define_singleton_method, :display, :dst?, :dup, :enum_for, :eql?, :equal?, :extend, :freeze, :friday?, :frozen?, :getgm, :getlocal, :getutc, :gmt?, :gmt_offset, :gmtime, :gmtoff, :hash, :hour, :httpdate, :inspect, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :instance_of?, :instance_variable_defined?, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set, :instance_variables, :is_a?, :isdst, :iso8601, :itself, :kind_of?, :localtime, :mday, :method, :methods, :min, :mon, :monday?, :month, :nil?, :nsec, :object_id, :private_methods, :protected_methods, :public_method, :public_methods, :public_send, :remove_instance_variable, :respond_to?, :rfc2822, :rfc822, :round, :saturday?, :sec, :send, :singleton_class, :singleton_method, :singleton_methods, :strftime, :subsec, :succ, :sunday?, :taint, :tainted?, :tap, :thursday?, :to_a, :to_date, :to_datetime, :to_enum, :to_f, :to_i, :to_r, :to_s, :to_time, :trust, :tuesday?, :tv_nsec, :tv_sec, :tv_usec, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :usec, :utc, :utc?, :utc_offset, :wday, :wednesday?, :xmlschema, :yday, :year, :zone]"
irb(main):028:0> t.to_datetime
=> #<DateTime: 2016-06-22T21:33:09+02:00 ((2457562j,70389s,767750206n),+7200s,2299161j)>
irb(main):029:0> t.instance_of?(Time)
=> true
irb(main):030:0> t.instance_of?(DateTime)
=> false
irb(main):031:0> tdt = t.to_datetime
=> #<DateTime: 2016-06-22T21:33:09+02:00 ((2457562j,70389s,767750206n),+7200s,2299161j)>
irb(main):032:0> tdt.instance_of?(Time)
=> false
irb(main):033:0> tdt.instance_of?(DateTime)
=> true
```

Here you have some interesting info [In Ruby on Rails, what's the difference between DateTime, Timestamp, Time and Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928275/in-ruby-on-rails-whats-the-difference-between-datetime-timestamp-time-and-da?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

In rails `5.2+` you can test if an object `is_a?`

```
Date.today.is_a?(Date) # -> true
Date.today.is_a?(DateTime) # -> false
```

Answer (score 3):

In Rails you can use the `acts_like?` method. Time does not `act_like_date?` so you need to check for date and time.

```rb
var.acts_like?(:date) || var.acts_like?(:time)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is an "easy way" without typing all the type variations of `Date` / `Time` / `DateTime` / `Timezone` out.

The simplest and fastest way is to do `dateTime.is_a?(DateTime)` or `Time.is_a?(Time)`, *repeat ad nausem* - which all will return a boolean.

Conversely you can also use `kind_of?.`

You might also be able to find a framework that has a function to check all of the variations of date and time.

Answer (score 1):

To find what class the module (or method) is located in, you use the `.class` function, this allows you to inspect Ruby objects to find out what class they are located in. The syntax for this looks like this: `object.class`. Here's some examples:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'date'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> d = Date.today
=> #<Date: 2016-06-22 ((2457562j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb(main):003:0> t = Time.now
=> 2016-06-22 18:52:24 -0500
irb(main):004:0> t.class
=> Time
irb(main):005:0> d.class
=> Date
```

As you can see this is an easy and simple way to find the class that the object is in.

Answer (score 1):

The Column objects returned by columns and columns_hash can then be used to get information such as the data type and default values, for example:

```
User.columns_hash['email'].type
=> :string
User.columns_hash['email'].default
=> nil
User.columns_hash['email'].sql_type
=> "varchar(255)"
```

([Source](https://thewebfellas.com/blog/accessing-column-information-with-activerecord))

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completion, another option would be:

```
def responds_to_datetime?(date)
  true if date.to_datetime rescue false
end
```